# Sklearn RandomForestClassifier predict_log_proba divide by zero error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use a RandomForestClassifier for an nlp problem but when I use the predict_log_proba method I get a divide by zero error. I took a look at the results from predict_proba method and found that the reason is because some of the probabilities for some classes (there are a total of 6 classes) are 0. So when the predict_log_proba tries to apply np.log to 0 it gets an error. Is there a parameter than can avoid this problem?

I know that predict_log_proba can be used correctly on a random forest classifier because I saw this example code use it and it worked fine: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_multiclass.html

I am using sklearn version 0.19 and the default parameter values for RandomForestClassifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if your model is outputting a zero probability for a given class, then the log probability for that class is negative infinity. So if you're summing over probabilities in the log space (or otherwise need this value), then obviously you can't work with this.

For this to occur in Random Forest, it means all of the trees are agreeing that the probability of this particular class for that particular data point is zero. You could mitigate this by increasing the number of trees (which would increase the chance at least one of them says that this example falls into that class). Or you could reduce the `max_depth` parameter to perhaps similar effect.

Alternatively you could just soften the outputs of your model before applying the logarithm, for instance by setting the output probabilities to min(max(p, 0.001), 0.999).

Hope that helps.